# Why does my dynamic to_char not work?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to return a list of results with the following WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM XTABLE 
WHERE MMONTH = to_char(to_date('03/2013','mm/yyyy'),'mm')
AND MYEAR = to_char(to_date('03/2013','mm/yyyy'),'yyyy')
```

where MMONTH is a column of type CHAR(3 Bytes) and MYEAR is a column of type CHAR(4 Bytes).

Why doesn't it work compared to

```
SELECT ... 
FROM XTABLE 
WHERE TO_DATE(MMONTH,'MM') = to_date(to_char(to_date('03/2012','mm/yyyy'),'mm'),'mm')
AND TO_DATE(MYEAR,'yyyy') = to_date(to_char(to_date('03/2012','mm/yyyy'),'yyyy'),'yyyy')
```

I am reluctant to change the format of the date ('03/2012') on the right as I have additional queries that use the same date, so I thought using just one type of date would be good.

Comment: What's actually in `MMONTH` - `'3  '`, `'03 '`, `'MAR'` (or your local equivalent), or something else? If it's the month number then I'm not sure why you wouldn't store that as a number, and if it has to be a string, why you'd choose `char` rather than `varchar2`.

Comment: MMONTH is '03', '04', so on.

Comment: I'm working with CHAR because that was what was given to me..

Comment: This separation of month and year is awful (and I accept that it may not be your fault, I'm just saying). Coding a condition for "between 2012-03 and 2013-05" is horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Oracle documentation,

> The CHAR data type specifies a fixed-length character string. Oracle ensures that all values stored in a CHAR column have the length specified by size. If you insert a value that is shorter than the column length, then Oracle blank-pads the value to column length.

So, if you insert '03' into `MMONTH` column, it will have a space at the end. The output of `to_char` function will return simply '03' without any space. Hence, when you compare it won't match.

Recommended way, is to change the datatype of your columns to VARCHAR2. You can also change the column size of MMONTH to 2.

Comment: So another way is to add TRIM to MMONTH?

Comment: VARCHAR2 is a better bet, I suppose.

Comment: just looking for a quick and dirty answer to solve this....though I agree changing the column datatypes would be better in the long run...Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Ramblin' Man's explanation of the problem, if you really can't change the data type, you could use `where trim(mmonth) =` which has index implications, or apply `rpad` or or `cast` to your `to_char`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a592/2) of all three options, but personally I'd go for the `cast` as that's most self-explanatory:

```
SELECT ...
FROM XTABLE 
WHERE MMONTH = cast(to_char(to_date('03/2013','mm/yyyy'),'mm') as char(3))
AND MYEAR = to_char(to_date('03/2013','mm/yyyy'),'yyyy');
```

Comment: um one more qn: what index implications?

Comment: Do you mean the searching of the table? like placing TRIM in a WHERE clause cauding search to be slowed down dramatically?

Comment: @user2427236 - if you had an index on `MMONTH` then having a function around it would stop the index being used. (Simplifying slightly). Whether that was `trim()` or your original `to_date()`. You could get around that with a function-based index, but it's easier to just avoid the issue if you can by not transforming the column you're filtering (or joining) on. Here that's easy, just make the right-hand side of the `=` the same data type as the column.